# Why the search query always use ID?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use `->find()`

I want to do query lie this

```
Where IdBiodata = '$IdBiodata'
```

Then I try this way :

```
Route::get('biodata/{IdBiodata}', function ($IdBiodata) {
    $databiodata = DB::table('Biodata')->find($IdBiodata);
        if(count($databiodata)) {
            return view('biodata/vew',compact('databiodata'));
        }else{
            echo "Data not Found";
        }
});
```

when I run it . I face this

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL
>   Server]Invalid column name 'id'. (SQL: select top 1 * from [Biodata]
>   where [id] = 1)

how can i fix it ? thanks in advance

My Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Biodata](
    [IdBiodata] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nama] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Umur] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Biodata] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IdBiodata] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Please use `Model::find()` not `DB::` query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your search query written using **query builder** not using **Eloquent ORM**.`find()` function Retrieving A Record By Primary Key and Primary Key always take column name as `id` untill and unless you can not defined externally.

So `$databiodata = DB::table('Biodata')->find($IdBiodata);` when you write this it's assume Primary key as id.

in `Eloquent ORM` you can change Primary Key

```
class Biodata extends Eloquent {

    protected $primaryKey = 'IdBiodata';

}
```

Now, you can write

```
Biodata::find($IdBiodata);
```

if you don't wan to use Eloquent ORM so simply use other function rather than `find()` use `where()`

```
$databiodata = DB::table('Biodata')->where('IdBiodata',$IdBiodata)->get();
```

SO now Replace Your Code using below code 
From this

```
$databiodata = DB::table('Biodata')->find($IdBiodata);
```

To

```
$databiodata = DB::table('Biodata')->where('IdBiodata',$IdBiodata)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

`find()` function always use the primary key .. you can use `where()` instead of `find()` if you're going to filter it by other field .. here's an example using your query

```
$databiodata = DB::table('Biodata')->where('IdBiodata',$IdBiodata)->get();
```

Comment: I get this error Undefined property: `Illuminate\Database\SqlServerConnection::$IdBiodata (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\boby\resources\views\biodata\vew.blade.php)`

Comment: updated my answer .. forgot to put `->get()` at the end of the script ..